# How can we compute the genus of the graph?

Tags: graph-theory

$V(G)=\{u_1,\cdots,u_7,v_1,\cdots,v_9, w_1,\cdots,w_5\}.$
 Set
 $$E_1=\{u_1u_j |2\leq j\leq 7\}\cup\{u_1v_j |j=1,3,5,6,8,9\}\cup\{u_1w_3,u_1w_4\};$$
 $$E_2=\{u_2u_j | j= 3, 4,6,7\}\cup\{u_2v_j |j=4,5,6,7\}\cup\{u_2w_5\};$$
 $$E_3=\{u_3u_j | j= 4,5,7\}\cup\{u_3v_j |j=1,7,8,9\}\cup\{u_3w_2\};$$
$$E_4=\{u_4u_j | j= 5,6\}\cup\{u_4v_j |j=1,2,3,4\}\cup\{u_4w_1\};$$
$$E_5=\{u_5u_j | j= 6,7\}\cup\{u_5v_j |j=4,5,6,7\}\cup\{u_5w_5\};$$
$$E_6=\{u_6u_7\}\cup\{u_6v_j |j=1,7,8,9\}\cup\{u_6w_2\};$$
$$E_7=\{u_7v_j |j=1,2,3,4\}\cup\{u_7w_1\};\;\;\;E_8=\{v_1v_5,v_1v_6\};$$
$$E_9=\{v_2v_7 \};\;\;E_{10}=\{v_3v_7 \};\;\;\;E_{11}=\{v_4v_8,v_4v_9 \},$$
$E(G)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{11}E_i$

Comment: Find a computer algebra system that does graph theory.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I want to know if the genus is equal to 2 or bigger than 2, by graph theory, not by computer.

Comment: You've got 21 vertices, and I-don't-know-how-many edges; who but a computer is going to be able to deal with a graph like that?

Comment: 62 edges, is there exists a subgraph with genus bigger than 2?

Comment: I don't know (I'm not a computer).

Comment: Thank you anyway for your consideration!

Comment: As an initial observation, note that the $u$ and $w$ vertices together give us a subgraph homeomorphic to $K_7$, which is maximal toroidal. To show the genus is greater than 2 it will be necessary to find a $K_9$ or $K_{5,5}$, or possibly some other forbidden graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph has genus greater than 2:

Since all vertices $w_1, \ldots w_5$ are of valency 1 or 2 they play no role in the embedding and we can just consider the underlying homeomorphic graph $H$ with the 16 vertices $\{ u_1, \ldots, u_7, v_1, \ldots v_9 \}$ and there are 57 edges including $u_2w_5u_5$, $u_3w_2u_6$ and $u_4w_1u_7$. Let us take $n=16$ and $m=57$.

If $H$ was embeddable on the double torus then it would have Euler Characteristic $\chi(H) =-2 = n-m+f$ and so $f=57-16-2= 39$, there are 39 faces. For a simple graph all faces must be triangles or larger, so we know that, counting around each face, we have at least $3f = 117$ edges, and each edge will have been counted twice. However, $2m= 114$ and so there are too many edges to fit $H$ on the double torus.

Comment: I am very grateful to you for your answer! Thanks for your kindness!

Comment: Can you help me compute the genus of graph $G:$ $V(G)=\{u_1,\cdots,u_8,v_1,\cdots,v_5\}$ and $E(G)=\{u_1u_3,u_1u_4,$ $u_1u_5,u_1u_6,$ $u_1u_7,u_1u_8,$ $u_1v_2,u_1v_3, $ $u_2u_3,u_2u_4,u_2u_5,$ $u_2u_6,u_2u_7,$ $u_2u_8,u_2v_2,u_2v_3$ $,u_3u_5,u_3u_6,$ $u_3u_7,u_3u_8,u_3v_4,$ $u_3v_5,u_4u_5,u_4u_6,$ $u_4u_7,u_4u_8,u_4v_4,$ $u_4v_5,u_5v_1,$ $u_6v_1,u_7v_1,u_8v_1.\}$  Is  genus of this graph  bigger than 2 or eual to 2?

Comment: The way StackExchange works is that you click on the arrow to say "This answer is useful" and mark it correct if it solves your problem:

Comment: That's the best way to encourage answers. Also, giving some more information rather than just an adjacency list would get more people interested, I feel...

Comment: having this as 1 comment was making it unreadable, for some reason, due to the large math in the comment above?